# Click Hardware back button in fragment to move back to GridActivity

Tags: android

- I have to move Detailfragment to GridActivity.Workflow for activity
  is GridActivity ->HomeActivity->DetailFragment.
- In GridActvity I am using an image button.On Click the image button I
  had set the position to move HomeActivity onArticlelistener.
- With this listener I can move to fragment using position.

**GridActivity1.java:**

```
 int position;

  ........
  ........
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn_tour:

                Intent i1=new Intent(GridActivity1.this,MainActivity.class);

                i1.putExtra("tour",2);
                i1.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(i1);
                break;
   }
  }
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTabChangeListener,ArticleSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_main_tab_fragment_layout);

     posGrid= getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");

        switch(posGrid){

            case 0:

            int posTour = getIntent().getIntExtra("tour", 0);
            articleSelected(posTour, "Tour Guide");

            break;
        }
      }

 @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(int position, String content)
    {
        articleSelected(position, content);

    }

 public void articleSelected(int position, String content)
   {

  if(position==2)
        {
            action_bar_hometext.setText(content);
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            DetailFragment newFragment = new DetailFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
   }
```

**DetailFragment.java:**

```
 public class TourGuideFirstFragment extends BaseFragment implements
        OnItemClickListener {
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tour_guide, container,
                false);

    return view;
    }
  }
```

- I don't need action bar back button.Because I am using navigation
  drawer in fragments.
- My issue is,when I click the hardware back button in DetailFragment I
  need to move directly to GridActivity.Now it is moving to HomeActivity then it back to GridActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a FragmentTransaction to the backstack, so in order to get rid of this you just have to remove the line from MainActivity

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

After that it should work as you want it to work

Comment: Works good.but I place a null inside addToBackStack.then how this will happen?

Comment: @Naruto the argument of this method acts like a tag, you can have a look at the [documentation page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)), in most cases you don't need it (that's why in most cases it's null) unless you have some kind of custom backstack handling. But even if it is null - the entry will still be added in the backstack